# Prevent hover on an element when scrolling event happened

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, marionette

I've built a dropdown widget using backbone/marionette that let you use keyboard to navigate up and down the dropdown list. I need to make the distinction between selected and highlighted so I am storing the boolean value in the list item model's isSelected and isHighlighted. Whenever the item is hovered, the isHighlighted is changed to true.

Here is my problem, I have setup the dropdown list to have a maxItem, so when there's too many items in the dropdown, I am showing a scrollbar so people can scroll to see more list items. When I use the keyboard navigation to navigate pass that maxItem limit, I call for an animate and scrollTop a certain distance so that the highlighted stay in view. The problem is if I happen to have the mouse within the dropdown list and this scrolling happened, it will trigger a mouseenter event on the item that is at where the mouse pointer is. Then it will change the hovered element's isHighlighted to true. That means the highlighted item went back up and when I use keyboard to navigate down again, it will go down from top instead of continue from where I was before.

Is there anyway I can prevent the mouseenter event when the scroll event fires?

Trying to include all the relevant code, hope this helps:

```
onKeyUp: function (event) {
    var key = event.which;

    switch (key) {
        case 38: // UP
            this.onUpArrow();
            break;
        case 40: // DOWN
            this.onDownArrow();
            break;
        default:
            // default method
    }
},
onDownArrow: function () {
    if (!this.isDropdownOpen()) {
        this.openDropdown();
    } else {
        this.dropdown.highlightNext();
        this.dropdown.scroll();
    }
},
```

In the other file, I have

```
events: {
    'mouseenter': 'onMouseEnter'
},
onMouseEnter: function (event) {
    this.triggerMethod('dropdown:option:mouseenter', {
        event: event,
        view: this,
        model: this.model
    });
},
```

In yet another file, I have

```
onDropdownOptionMouseenter: function () {
    var data = _.last(arguments),
        event = data.event,
        view = data.view;
    view.highlight();
}
```

At this point, the scrolling happened, and mouseenter trigger has been fired and the highlighting changed. I just don't know where I can add the code to prevent the browser to recognize the mouseenter. Am I suppose to add custom events for this? That is a lot of work imo, there has to be an easier solution.

Comment: I had this issue before. Post your code so I can guide you to a solution.

Comment: @Seebiscuit Added codes that is relevant, hope this is enough. Thanks.

Comment: Yup, since you're going across views you'll have to either use an messaging system (event aggregator) or a global variable (don't do that, code stink). Want me to show you a sample?

Comment: Yeah, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Setting up an event aggregator

Making an event aggregator in Backbone is trivial, just `extend` the events object,

```
window.vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

We attach the event aggregator, `vent`, to the global scope so that anyone can listen in.

If you're using Marionette you can use the built-in aggregator in `Backbone.Wreqr` the built-in Marionette messaging system (**Note:** `Wreqr` will be switched out with a new messaging API, `Radio`, starting with Marionette v.3, but I have it from a good source that the update manager *should* migrate all `Wreqr` instances to `Radio`).

Createing an event aggregator is a matter of calling,

```
window.vent = new Backbone.Wreqr.EventAggregator();
```

Now to help your problem, we'll use the event aggregator to set up a pubsub system, where your item's view will subscribe to an event that will help them to properly react to a scroll. The view that manages the scroll will be publishing this event.

**Note:** `Backbone.Wreqr`can also be equipped to use `Channels` if you want to create independent messaging pipelines. Check out the [docs](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.wreqr).

### Subscribing

So let's set up the subscriptions. In the item's view do

```
initialize: function ()  {
  this.listenTo(vent, "dropdown:before:scroll", function() {
    this.isScrolling = true;
  }
  this.listenTo(vent, "dropdown:end:scroll", function() {
    this.isScrolling = false;
  }
}
```

### Publishing

The events we just subscribed to will be published right before and after the `scrollTop` call, by triggering the event on `vent`. So you'd rewrite the maxlimit checker like this,

```
if (currItem > maxItem) {
  vent.trigger("dropdown:before:scroll");
  someElement.scrollTop();
  vent.trigger("dropdown:end:scroll");
}
```

The items listening to these events will know that you're scrolling since trigger events are **synchronous** and will fire in the correct order.

### Preventing the highlight

Finally, now that you're publishing the `scrollTop` event and your items are listening for it, you make sure that the item that encounters a `mouseenter` knows when *not* to highlight.

```
onMouseEnter: function (event) {
  if (!this.isScrolling) {
    this.triggerMethod('dropdown:option:mouseenter', {
        event: event,
        view: this,
        model: this.model
    });
  }
},
```

Comment: Glad I could help! Leave a comment if you're having any issues.

Comment: Yeah, I actually have a question regarding this. I am not too familiar with the Marionette.Wreqr so this basically is a global event aggregator right? What if there are multiple instances of my components, does Wreqr make a separate global channel for each instance? How do I know which event is for which instance?

Comment: Yes, unless you use `Channels` (see the link on the Answer), all your events will be "collected" by this global aggregator. So anyone listening in on "this:event" will invoke its associated callback.